# List and launch metro apps in Windows 10 with C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I need to list the installed metro apps in a Windows 10 system.
Starting from the list I would like to launch any installed app.
The only requirement is that I don't have to use the PackageManager class.

I've just solved the problem in Win 8 starting from this inspiring code in PowerShell http://poshcode.org/3740
Now I would like to do the same in Windows 10 but it seems to me that the registry mapping for metro apps has strongly changed since 8/8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I have found a native powershell command in Windows 10 that may be of some use.

[Get-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx)

For example, to get a list of app names:

```
> Get-AppxPackage | Select Name

Name
----
Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin
Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost
Microsoft.AccountsControl
Microsoft.BioEnrollment
Microsoft.LockApp
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge
Microsoft.Windows.AssignedAccessLockApp
Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager
Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls
Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost
Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI
Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider
Windows.ContactSupport
windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Windows.MiracastView
Windows.PrintDialog
Windows.PurchaseDialog
windows.devicesflow
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00
Microsoft.Windows.Cortana
Microsoft.WindowsFeedback
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1
Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Universal
4DF9E0F8.Netflix
Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Universal
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
Microsoft.Appconnector
Microsoft.WindowsStore
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.0
Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00
Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2
```

I personally only have one 3rd party metro app installed, Netflix, and I've even uninstalled some of the default Microsoft apps.

If you wanted to exclude Microsoft and Windows apps from this query:

```
> Get-AppxPackage | ? {$_.Name -notlike "Microsoft*" -AND $_.Name -notlike "Windows*"}| Select Name

Name
----
4DF9E0F8.Netflix
```

I'm yet to find a way to launch the apps from this, but I'm sure this is a step in the right direction. ;)

**Edit:**

Okay, this turned out to be so simple, and yet surprisingly hard to find out...

```
Start Shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!App
```

This AppID can be retrieved from the following, which as far as I can tell, lists everything in the start menu.

```
Get-StartApps
```

It may also be able to be retrieved from the Get-AppxPackages cmdlet by appending "!App" onto the end of the PackageFamilyName property.

```
Get-AppxPackage | % { $_.PackageFamilyName + "!App" }
```

I found this to work with some, but not all.
It worked with Netflix, Calculator, Store for example. But Microsoft Edge was "!MicrosoftEdge" not "!App". So I wouldn't say it's a reliable method unless you can identify or retrieve the suffix from somewhere else, which is why I found Get-StartApps to be better for me. (I was personally only looking for a way to launch Netflix by script / shortcut...)

Comment: Unfortunately the question asks for a C# solution.
I tried to get the source code of the involved assemblies of your PowerShell solution but I finally found the c:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll that is not a managed library.